# Почему padding задаётся от body а не от div

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать 10% сверху и сниху отступ (padding) в правом (зелёном) диве - но он задаётся от body а не от правого (зелёного) дива
Почему?
[image: нужен отступ 10% сверху и снизу]

**CSS** правого (зелёного) дива

```
  .form {
        display: inline-block;
        flex-flow: column;
        border: 6px solid blue;
        grid-gap: 5%;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 5%;
        padding-bottom: 5%;
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/padding#%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F padding в процентах высчитывается от **ширины** (!) **родительского** блока.

Comment: Для более развёрнутого ответа приведите html и весь соответсвующий CSS, а не одно правило